# VBA array of range reading values and not ranges

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, for-loop

I'm trying to create several arrays of ranges so that I can then cycle through each array and take the different values from each range but for some reason, it reads the first range of the array as just a value and therefore won't union with following cells the array is only ever a single value.

I've looked at a lot of examples online, as well as earlier projects and I can't figure out why this is happening. I don't mind creating an array of values instead of ranges, I just need to make sure I have an actual array,

```
Dim subjectArray As Range
Dim durationArray As Range
Dim rw As Long
Dim i As Range
 
 Set subjectArray = Nothing
 Set durationArray = Nothing

 For rw = 4 To 200
 
 If Left(Cells(rw, 2).Value, 3) = "ATT" And Cells(rw, 2).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
If subjectArray Is Nothing Then Set subjectArray = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & rw) Else Set subjectArray = Union(subjectArray, ActiveSheet.Range("B" & rw))
 If durationArray Is Nothing Then Set durationArray = ActiveSheet.Range("F" & rw + 2) Else Set durationArray = Union(durationArray, ActiveSheet.Range("F" & rw + 2))
 Else
 
 End If

next rw

 For Each i In subjectArray

Debug.Print subjectArray(i) 'placeholder function for testing
Debug.Print durationArray(i) 'placeholder function for testing

next i
```

I am after something that I could loop through the different arrays at the same time, where each loop inputs the valueso f the differnet arrays into their corresponding function and output each different value of the array, but because it only reads the array as a single value, it gives an error on subjectArray(i).

If there is a way to condense the multiple arrays into one array, I'm all ears.

Edit: Clarified the use case to include the multiple arrays

Comment: replace `Debug.Print subjectArray(i)` with `Debug.Print i.Value` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-eachnext-statement

Comment: This is something I should have mentioned in the question. I was hoping to make multiple arrays (They'll all be the same size) and have them each do a different thing in the 2nd loop. I guess this would require For Each i in... and then For Each J in... or is there a way to condense this into one loop?

Answer (score 2):

`subjectArray` is not an Array, it is a (non-contiguous) Range. You can loop over all single cells using `For Each` (as you do). The variable that you use in the loop (in your case `i`) is also a Range (Cells are Ranges), and to get the value, you simple use the `Value`-property (I renamed the variable to `cell`)

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In subjectArray
    Debug.Print cell.Value 
Next cell
```

As an alternative, you can use a "normal" For loop, in that case the variable is numeric and you can use it as index:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 to subjectArray.Cells.Count
    Debug.Print subjectArray(i).Value
Next i
```

---

The problem with your code:
What you do is to use the cell of the for each loop as index into `subjectArray`. So VBA will use the *content* of the cell as index:

If the cell contains a numeric value (eg 100), you will get the 100th cell of `subjectArray`. And as said, `subjectArray` is not an Array - even if `subjectArray` contains only 50 cells, you will get a result (and not an out of error index).
If the cell contains something different (eg the string "ABC"), you will get a type mismatch error, because `subjectArray("ABC")` is not valid.

Comment: I'm too low level to +1, but the alternative you gave was what I wanted to achieve, thank you!